# single actionlistener for multiple buttons

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, actionlistener

Can anyone help me out how to add **single action listener on multiple buttons**?
Here is my code of multiple action listener for multiple buttons.
I have also tried taking one common button for an action listener for all buttons. Can anyone please suggest me a relevant answer. I am a beginner and I don't have much knowledge in java.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();     //object of JFrame
        JLabel firstValue, secondValue, result, answer;     //declaration of JLabel
        JTextField one, two;     //declaration of JTextField
        JButton addition, subtraction, multiplication, division;     //declaration of JButton

        //Label for first value
        firstValue = new JLabel("First Value:");
        firstValue.setBounds(50,70,100,30);
        frame.add(firstValue);      

        //Label for second value
        secondValue = new JLabel("Second Value:");
        secondValue.setBounds(50,120,100,30);
        frame.add(secondValue);     

        //TextFields for first value    
        one = new JTextField();
        one.setBounds(170, 70, 105, 30);
        frame.add(one);

        //TextFields for second value
        two = new JTextField();
        two.setBounds(170, 120, 105, 30);
        frame.add(two);

        //Button for addition
        addition = new JButton("+");
        addition.setBounds(50, 170, 45, 30);
        frame.add(addition);

        //Button for subtraction
        subtraction = new JButton("-");
        subtraction.setBounds(110, 170, 45, 30);
        frame.add(subtraction);

        //Button for multiplication
        multiplication = new JButton("*");
        multiplication.setBounds(170, 170, 45, 30);
        frame.add(multiplication);

        //Button for division
        division = new JButton("/");
        division.setBounds(230, 170, 45, 30);
        frame.add(division);

        //Label for Result
        result = new JLabel("Result");
        result.setBounds(50, 220, 100, 30);
        frame.add(result);

        //TextFields for first value    
        answer = new JLabel();
        answer.setBounds(170, 220, 105, 30);
        frame.add(answer);

        //actionListener for addition button
        addition.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //logic for addition
                int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(one.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(two.getText());
                answer.setText(Integer.toString(finalAnswer));

            }
        });


        //actionListener for subtraction button
        subtraction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //logic for addition
                int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(one.getText()) - Integer.parseInt(two.getText());
                answer.setText(Integer.toString(finalAnswer));              
            }
        });

        //actionListener for multiplication button
        multiplication.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //logic for addition
                int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(one.getText()) * Integer.parseInt(two.getText());
                answer.setText(Integer.toString(finalAnswer));              
            }
        });     

        //actionListener for division button
        division.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //logic for addition
                int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(one.getText()) / Integer.parseInt(two.getText());
                answer.setText(Integer.toString(finalAnswer));              
            }
        });     

        frame.setSize(400,400);     //set size of JFrame with width and height
        frame.setLayout(null);      //set layout type by null
        frame.setVisible(true);     //set JFrame visible by boolean value true/false    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you would do something like this (you could append this within your Calculator class):

```
class Calculator {

  private JButton subtraction;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your code

    // button example
    subtraction = new JButton("-");
    subtraction.addActionListener(new Listener());

    // your code
  }

  class Listener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (e.getSource() == nameOfJButton) {
        // do the action for this button
      } else if (e.getSource() == nameOfAnotherButton) {
        // you get the idea
      }
    }

  }

}
```

And now, you can alter your code like so:

```
// actionListener for addition button
addition.addActionListener(new Listener());
```

Comment: so i need to create one more class **listener** in my code right?

Comment: @MaitriPatel correct, I edited my answer to show *where* you would place it - this makes the most sense for me when I'm working on big projects with multiple `Listener()`s

Comment: **subtraction cannot be resolved to a variable** i am getting this error on button names

Comment: @MaitriPatel ah - I should have seen that coming. You will have to declare your JButtons *at the class level* of Calculator to access them from `Listener()` - see edit

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. My problem is now solved. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MaitriPatel please accept the answer so others know the question is closed - cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little bit advanced solution for your problem. The main idea is to put your operation as parameter for your action. Also I use class `AbstractAction` instead of `ActionListener` to define the buttons. It allows to combine text and action. So the code looks smaller and smarter.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/**
 * <code>ButtonExample</code>.
 */
public class ButtonExample {
    private JTextField one, two;

    private final JLabel answer = new JLabel();

    private class ArithmeticAction extends AbstractAction {
        private final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> arithmeticFunction;

        public ArithmeticAction(String name, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> arithmeticFunction) {
            super(name); // set name of button
            this.arithmeticFunction = arithmeticFunction;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Integer firstOperand = Integer.valueOf(one.getText());
            Integer secondOperand = Integer.valueOf(two.getText());
            Integer result = arithmeticFunction.apply(firstOperand, secondOperand);
            answer.setText(result.toString());
        }
    }

    private void initUI() {
        one = new JTextField(5);
        two = new JTextField(5);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));
        panel.add(new JLabel("First value:"));
        panel.add(one);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Second value:"));
        panel.add(two);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Result:"));
        panel.add(answer);
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 5));
        JPanel operations = new JPanel();
        operations.add(new JButton(new ArithmeticAction("+", (a, b) -> a + b)));
        operations.add(new JButton(new ArithmeticAction("-", (a, b) -> a - b)));
        operations.add(new JButton(new ArithmeticAction("*", (a, b) -> a * b)));
        operations.add(new JButton(new ArithmeticAction("/", (a, b) -> a / b)));
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        frm.add(panel);
        frm.add(operations, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ButtonExample()::initUI);
    }
}
```

Little explanation:

`BiFunction` is a standard interface, that becomes two arguments, and returns a value. You can implement it like this:

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> sum = (a, b) -> a + b;
```

It means that the function takes two parameters: `a` and `b` and returns the value `a + b`. This possibility was addad in Java 8.

Comment: Hey!!! I have gone through your solution. But I didn't understand much and also I tried to implement it but I got bit confused as I don't have much knowledge about this language and also I am a beginner.